# Apple Keyboard on Vista

Tags: windows-vista

Has anybody been able to get the "fn" key on the Apple keyboard to work in Vista? Not a copy running in Boot Camp, but the "real thing". I have tried many tools to remap keys, but I have yet to find one that will detect that key.

Comment: Which f'n key is giving you trouble? Oh, wait, that's not what you meant...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "get it to work?"

Do the F-keys only work if fn is pressed? Are you trying to get the volume/play/brightness buttons to work? Does fn do nothing?

The last two are fairly common with various utils to solve. I've never heard of the fn key not working at all...

Comment: What do you mean by the 'real thing'? Bootcamp is simply a tool allowing you to dual boot, and a set of drivers. The drivers are needed for Windows to function properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Apple says at the bottom of the [Keyboard mapping KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1167),  you need the Apple Keyboard driver that comes with Bootcamp to get that to work. Happytocode.com has a few tips on how to get the driver and on using Apple Keyboard on Windows Vista

1. [Getting the driver](http://www.happytocode.com/post/Apple-Aluminium-keyboard-Boot-Camp-20-Windows-drivers.aspx)
2. [Having a toggle for the FN Key](http://www.happytocode.com/post/Small-tool-to-manage-the-Apple-keyboard-fn-key.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question [yesterday](https://superuser.com/questions/629/apple-wireless-aluminium-keyboard-on-windows) and came up with [uawks](http://code.google.com/p/uawks/) as the best solution to the problem - it works!

Bootcamp isn't so good on a non-mac machine - I've noticed it hangs for 30 seconds or so on bootup (I guess it's looking for hardware that doesn't exist on my pc).