# Using an Apple compact keyboard on Windows how do I enable special keys like Home and PgUp?

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard

I'm currently using an [Apple compact keyboard](http://images.appleinsider.com/applekeyboard-4.png) at work on a laptop running Windows Vista. At home and on my previous jobs I always used Linux computers where it is dead simple to configure that you are using an Apple keyboard and all the special keys works as expected. On Windows I have not been able to locate any such mappings in the keyboard configuration.

The bindings I am missing the most are:

- Cmd+Right => End
- Cmd+Left  => Home
- Cmd+Up    => PgUp
- Cmd+Down  => PgDn

I have tried using a Windows application I found called [MacroMaker](http://members.ij.net/anthonymathews/Macromaker.htm) but it does not appear to work and I couldn't find an offical website to ask for support. Apart from MacroMaker I also gave [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) a go but I don't think it supports combining multiple keypresses into one result.

My preferred solution would of course be to find a keyboard mapping that plugs directly into Windows' native input stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) it allows you to map pretty much anything to anything, and allows chords if you want as well as multiple sequential key presses.

Comment: Thanks I ended up using Autohotkey and followed this guide: http://blog.newslacker.net/2011/01/using-apple-keyboard-with-windows-wired.html

Answer (score 0):

## probably same as [Apple Wireless (aluminium) Keyboard on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/629/apple-wireless-aluminium-keyboard-on-windows) ?

Just post my answer here:

Solution: **update your Apple Wireless Keyboard Driver**, then restart your PC, then Fn + Arrow work fine.

Just tested today: Working on PC with Windows 7 Pro 64 bit (note: it is NOT a Mac).

[image: Apple Wireless keyboard in Windows (PC)] [bigger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Dv0.png)

**Steps:**

1. Download latest Bootcamp drivers from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638
2. Extract the file, then open folder \BootCamp5.0.5033\BootCamp\Drivers\Apple
3. Run BootCamp.msi (do NOT run setup.exe as it will say it is unsupported on this computer model)
4. Wait for the driver installation finish, then restart your PC.
5. On next bootup, run Bootcamp (surprisingly you can !!!),  go to Keyboard and choose whether you want F1,F2,etc as standard keyboard function.
   For more info, check the Apple Wireless Keyboard keyboard mapping in Windows kb http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1171

That's it. No need extra software, just latest drivers from Apple.